# Logging without loss of time

Tags: php

Greetz fellows!

I'm looking for a way to log actions of a CLI script without losing time. I did some benchmarks and I figured out that by `echo`ing someting after each action, the script will be nearly 2x slower and by appending actions to a log file it'll be 17x times slower.

So, anyone has a solution?

Comment: Not really. Doing stuff takes time... But it usually doesn't really matter because it's a question of microseconds. What are you doing exactly? It's hard to believe that `echo` statements could slow down a script this badly

Comment: @Pekka - Suspect it's the process of displaying the echoed content on the terminal,etc. that's slowing things down.

Comment: How are you attempting to save to a log file? Is the log file on local storage? (Not remote or a SAN or something odd.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CLI, I guess you can test with this:

```
YOUR_SCRIPT.php > /tmp/log.txt &
```

Inside `YOUR_SCRIPT.php`

```
<?
  /* some action */
  echo date('r').some_action_1()."\n";   <-- this is bad  # REMARK 1
  echo date('r').some_action_2()."\n";

  echo date('r'), some_action_1(), "\n"; <-- this is nice # REMARK 2
  echo date('r'), some_action_2(), "\n";
?>
```

And monitor using

```
tail -f /tmp/log.txt
```

The reason `REMARK 1` slow is because function execute first, while `REMAKR 2` does not (output first)

Answer (score 0):

Logging to a file should be a lot faster than echoing to the screen (it's the process of displaying the text that's most likely the limit).

As such, you could simply write the debug to a file and (if so required) "`tail -f`" the file to see the live debug. (I'm presuming you're running under Linux/Unix, etc.)

As a suggestion:

```
function logDebugToFile($string) {

    // Set defaults...
    $filename = 'INSERT REQUIRED PATH/FILENAME HERE.log';

    $ourFP = fopen($filename, 'a+');
    if (is_resource($ourFP)) {
        fwrite($ourFP, $string."\n");
        fclose($ourFP);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's what I did an it takes a lot of extra time.

Comment: @sexyprout - If you're doing a lot of logging, it would make sense to open the file at the start and close it at the end, rather than the above. That said, this should still be a lot faster than outputting to the screen. Is the log file on the local filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Log into a TCP resource/socket. And add a listener in the network on it. So there is no I/O.